# How to fix when python recognizes only one .kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I just started learning Kivy today. The book i am referring to uses kv files. The problem is when i create more than one .kv file, and when i import the other one, it doesn't work. Please any detailed help will be appreciated as i am a complete beginner. Thanks

I already searched alot and tried from places, but nothing seems to work.

## main.py

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
    from kivy.lang import Builder

    class AddLocationForm(BoxLayout):
        pass

    class WeatherApp(App):
        pass

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        WeatherApp().run()
```

## AddLocationForm.kv

```
    AddLocationForm:
    <AddLocationForm@BoxLayout>:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            TextInput:
            Button:
                text: "Search"
            Button:
                text: "Current Location"
```

## weather.kv

```
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Hello"
        Label:
            text: "Awesome"
        Label:
            text: "World"
```

I want it to print the strings, and show the button as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use Kv Language Directives, `include <file>`

## Snippets - weather.kv

```
#:include AddLocationForm.kv

AddLocationForm:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Hello"
        Label:
            text: "Awesome"
        Label:
            text: "World"
```

## Snippets - AddLocationForm.kv

```
<AddLocationForm@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
        Button:
            text: "Search"
        Button:
            text: "Current Location"
```

## Output

[image: Result]

## [Kv language » Lang Directives](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#lang-directives)

> ```
> include <file>
> ```
>
> Syntax:
>
> ```
> #:include [force] <file>
> ```
>
> Includes an external kivy file. This allows you to split complex
>   widgets into their own files. If the include is forced, the file will
>   first be unloaded and then reloaded again. For example:
>
> ```
> # Test.kv
> #:include mycomponent.kv
> #:include force mybutton.kv
>
> <Rule>:
>     state: 'normal'
>     MyButton:
>     MyComponent:
>
> # mycomponent.kv
> #:include mybutton.kv
>
> <MyComponent>:
>     MyButton:
> # mybutton.kv
>
> <MyButton>:
>     canvas:
>         Color:
>             rgb: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
>         Rectangle:
>             pos: self.pos
>             size: (self.size[0]/4, self.size[1]/4)
> ```

Comment: Can you explain, why do we need to make the root widget as #AddLocationForm.kv in the other file which was just printing Labels? (sorry if its a dumb question, but if you can explain, it will be clearer)

Comment: In my example, I made `AddLocationForm:` as the root rule for a nice presentation view. If *weather.kv* is the root, all your widgets will appear horizontally, and the presentation view looked cramped. The default `orientation` of `BoxLayout` is `horizontal`.

Comment: You cannot define your root widget in an included `kv` file. Not documented, but true.

Comment: The app will runs fine with a *root rule* in each *kv* files. For example, a *root rule*, `AddLocationForm:` in the included *kv* file (`AddLocationForm.kv`) and another *root rule*, `BoxLayout:` in `weather.kv`. In this scenario, the *root rule* used by Kivy App is from `weather.kv` which is a `BoxLayout:` and the *root rule* from `AddLocationForm.kv` is ignored. **Kivy will throw an error if there are more than one *root rule* in a *kv* file. It is generally regarded as *‘best practice’* to have only one root object in *kv* file.**

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Builder` to load kv files or strings.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file("kvfile1.kv")
Builder.load_file("kvfile2.kv")
```